# How to make a registration and login system using django?

Tags: python, django

I want to create a registration and login system I have made the registration form but I'm not able to carry out the authentication part of it.

**Models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class profile(models.Model):
    WORK = (
            ('School', 'School'),
            ('Collage', 'Collage'),
            ('Job', 'Job')
        )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    age = models.IntegerField() 
    work = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=WORK)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

**Forms.py** *For the registration of user*

```
from django import forms
from .models import profile



class registration_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post 
        fields={
        "name",
        "email",
        "username",
        "password",
        "work",
        "age"
        }
```

I want to use the above database to authenticate the user how can i do that ?(also I dont want to use any third party library like django-registration)

Comment: Did you look at django.contrib.auth? Provides common building blocks to do what you want, and prevents you from doing things like storing your passwords in plaintext in your database...

Comment: Yaa but it brings the django admin into play and has a lot less fields than i want

Comment: **Don't roll your own authentication system like this, it's insecure**. You should not store passwords as plain text as you are doing. The Django auth app allows you to create a [custom user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) with extra fields. You can use the auth app without enabling the admin - they are separate apps.

Comment: @Alasdair then please tell me how to use the django auth app without enabling the admin and for password i will surely create an extra field

Comment: Start with [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/) and if you get stuck, ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Alasdair is right, you don't need the django.contrib.admin in order to use the django.contrib.auth.

Next a solution, that make use of django generic class based views.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Profile(AbstractUser):
    WORK = (
        ('School', 'School'),
        ('Collage', 'Collage'),
        ('Job', 'Job')
    )
                                                        )
    age = models.IntegerField() 
    work = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=WORK)
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_users_app.Profile'
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'  # Where our login page is
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.views import login as django_login_view
from django.views.generic import FormView


class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'my_users_app/login.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        usuario = form.get_user()

        django_login_view(self.request, usuario)
        return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**urls.py**

```
from my_users_app.views import LoginView
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

**login.html**

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Note:

- In order to make your own User model, you need to configure the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, and inherit from `AbstractUser`.
- The `AuthenticationForm` will validate the username/password and will trigger the form_valid.
- I'm using `from django.contrib.auth.views import login` to import the django login view who is responsible to make the login action once the form has been validated.