# User login system in Django, with MongoDB as the primary database

Tags: django, django-forms, mongoengine

So, here is the thing. I want the best method to log users on my website. I've already made a registration system that registers details of Users in the mongoDB using model forms.
I don't understand how to login the user in th website. Do I fetch the user data from the DB and match with the the form data entered by the user to log in, what is the best practice?

Comment: Please take a look if this can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817772/how-to-make-a-registration-and-login-system-using-django .The stackoverflow community is vast and has usually already faced the problem you might be facing. Please do run a quick search query in future to see if an already existing QnA might be helpful.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks :)